# Does SOLR use up a lot of memory on a server?

Tags: java, php, sql, mysql, html

I have **no experience** with SOLR.

Does SOLR use more memory on a server than, say, MySQL?

I am about to purchase a VPS-package, but they come in different sizes, as you can imagine...

I contacted the providers today by email, and told them that I was planning on using SOLR, which requires a Java installation.

Their response was that it would work fine, but that I should go with a more expensive VPS package than I was initially going to order, because "Java applets require a lot of memory".

Here are the two packages they provide. I was initially going to order the standard package:

**STANDARD Package:**

- Processor cores: 1
- RAM: 512 MB
- Guaranteed RAM: 256 MB
- Disk System: RAID5/50
- Price: $20 / Month

**GOLD Package:**

- Processor cores: 8
- RAM: 2048 MB
- Guaranteed RAM: 1024 MB
- Disk system: RAID10
- Price: $50 / Month

I have about 25,000 records in a MySQL table, each of which has about 10 fields. The site is PHP-based. No heavy stuff at all, actually!

I have never had any VPS before, so any guidance is appreciated! Which do you think I should order?

If you need more info, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *absolutely no* experience using SOLR, my natural reaction is to be safe than sorry, therefore personally I would go with the GOLD Package. Although it is another $30/month, it has more RAM and processor cores which can come in handy for later down the line.

I know this answer could have been more helpful if I had any experience with VPS or SOLR, but I thought I would voice my opinion. I hope this helps, good luck.